# Please help understand how $ax^2+by-c=0$ is NP Complete

Tags: diophantine-equations, computational-complexity

I found a statement that $ax^2+by-c=0$ is NP Complete. However I am unable to find any document showing the proof.

There is a paper on few pay-walled sites but they are out of reach for me. The document is NP-complete decision problems for quadratic polynomials by Manders and Adleman, and one copy is here : http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=803627

The formal statement of the problem is : Given positive integers $a, b, c \ge 0$, find positive integers $x, y \ge 0$ such that $ax^2+by-c=0$. I am also unable to figure out how a 3SAT problem might be reduced to this form.

If someone can explain or guide me to a tutorial or explanation for this online it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I just realised I hadn't put up the full problem statement. My bad. I have edited the problem to correct this. Hope this clarifies what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Page 150](https://books.google.com/books?id=z4zMiZyAE1kC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=np+complete+quadratic+diophantine+equations&source=bl&ots=901ygsmYYj&sig=C_h7hsWbIz0fMP5BqeIjLQA90OY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFYQ6AEwB2oVChMIiIC7kuimxwIVipeICh1QdgTZ#v=onepage&q=np%20complete%20quadratic%20diophantine%20equations&f=false) of *The Nature of Computation* by Moore and Mertens has it; it's a reduction from 

Subset Sum.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is great.